Is it legal to send pressed flowers to the United States via mail?
Is it legal to send pressed flowers from my garden to the United States via mail. If it is legal, what rules are relevant?
The flowers are common snowdrop (Galanthus nivalis) and crocus vernus.
Crocus vernus flower:

Snowdrop:


why would it not be?

@TigerGuy it's a reasonable question; customs laws can be quite complicated.

How could this be an RSLA? Is it just because it says "my" garden rather than "a" garden?

For intranational USPS deliveries, plants can be mailed.  However, they are subject to numerous restrictions, covered by Publication 52.5.56 Plants and
Publication 14 - Prohibitions and Restrictions on Mailing Plants, Animals, and Related Matter. These restrictions include rules about pests, packaging, etc. Other delivery services typically have similar rules.
In the case of international deliveries, the plant must be declared and must be accompanied by a phytosanitary certificate.  For high volume deliveries, the sender will probably also need a permit. Typically, the way you get such a phytosanitary certificate is that you pay a third-party company to pack/sterilize/prepare your plant in a legally compliant manner, then they include the certificate as part of this service.
